# Can the router owner access a user's internet history?

Tags: router, internet, history

I share the internet bill with my downstairs neighbor, but the router is in his house and legally belongs to him. Can he access my internet history? If so, how can I block him or protect me from him being able to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the router setup, he could be logging all the traffic, and could see where your traffic is going.  Note that this is true in any case where you're connecting to someone else's router - e.g. public wifi.

The only way to prevent snooping of the traffic that you're sending would be to encrypt all your communications - common ways of doing this include sending all traffic through an SSH tunnel or a VPN.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have an opinion about what would be the best free option to encrypt my browsing?
Is using TOR a good option? It feels like an overkill solution to a minor annoyance. Thanks!

Comment: Tor is peftect for that.